# Ajax post call not reaching Django view

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-views

In my django site i have an API view that is supposed to increment an integer field when called. However, the ajax call says the view is an invalid url. I have tried changing the url multiple times and changing the view.

Here's the error message from console
[image: Error message]

Here's my javascript ajax call

```
    function post_(amount){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '127.0.0.1:8000/increment/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "amount": amount,
                "user": "{{ user.username }}",
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Error Message: ");
                console.log(error);

            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the django view this ajax function is supposed to call

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Increment(request):
    amount = request.data['amount']
    #username_m = request.data['user']
    #profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=username_m)
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    print(profile)
    profile.coins += amount
    profile.save(update_fields=['coins'])
    return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
```

And here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('increment/', views.Increment, name='increment'),

]
```

Thanks

Comment: change  url: '127.0.0.1:8000/increment/', to  url: '/increment/', and return JsonResponse insted of Response

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `/increment/` as AJAX url. This will add `/increment/` to your localhost domain.

Answer (score 0):

For Absolute path try using

```
url: 'http://localhost:8000/increment/'
```

or

```
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/increment/'
```